# Changing the domain canonical name

Tags: apache, dns

i have a number of domains that all point to www.domainA.com. now i need to change it so that all requests will point to www.domainB.com. notes: it is a virtual host, the machine also hosts other domains. and it wasn't me who setup the server on the first place.

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In your domainA's .conf

```
RedirectMatch 301 (.*) http://www.domainb.com$1
```

This will forward all requests coming in on domainA to the equivalent url on domain B, doing a 301 "moved permanently" status, so hopefully any crawlers following those links will update things to just point at domainB instead of going through domainA